# POST request in javascript failing, but can see successful response in fiddler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, fiddler

```
 var post_url = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?code=" + callbackCode + "&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=" + client_id + "&client_secret=" + client_secret + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_url;
            $.ajax({
                url: post_url,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
            }).done(function (data) {
                app.showNotification("successful post request", "asdf");
            }).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
               var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
               app.showNotification('failure with http POST request', err);
            });
```

This the code I use to send a `POST` request. For some reason this always fails with an error message 'error'. However I have been monitoring fiddler while this code executes. I clearly get a response to the `POST` request. (Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points to post an image, but I can email a screenshot if anyone wants to see).

I'm not sure what's going wrong here. Additionally, I put a breakpoint in my code, just before the application sends the ajax request and copy pasted the `post_url` into a fiddler `POST` request and I got the response. Does anyone have any ideas?

A sample response in fiddler looks like:

```
{
"id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D90000000vD7XEAU/00590000002jrEwAAI",
"issued_at":"1405068616953",
"scope":"full",
"instance_url":"https://ap1.salesforce.com",
"token_type":"Bearer",
"id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IjE4OCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0MDUwNjg3MzYsInN1YiI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9naW4uc2FsZXNmb3JjZS5jb20vaWQvMDBEOTAwMDAwMDB2RDdYRUFVLzAwNTkwMDAwMDAyanJFd0FBSSIsImF1ZCI6IjNNVkc5WTZkX0J0cDR4cDZ0azIxU0ljV1hKU1ZEWFdPUlhZa3owX1djVF9YbmpsOV9BMVc1RHR4Z2VST0NNemd5cVVkbDBUVVVvT0JZR3czVWx1Y2IiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvZ2luLnNhbGVzZm9yY2UuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNDA1MDY4NjE2LCJjX2hhc2giOiJzbTYzV240eVUtcVNSSXFjZGl5RzR3In0.CIGT_wWfW8otAGeKnSlmerfkpr41t5oD0djS80K32Z51O9y9_jCjYU4jJyJ3wVhRdRmuF3YXBn6_sw4waheb7FsTO4agZWikb-fOsTi8nVKQnoCYXTgJC1N93Edek9pzm1y8uONFel9P0cT1ddpVsUGSgI3LBksfJ_XJux0ichHNDuHSL2dPJlbnvOO2XOOV-tSMtXT3C8KK7FGs2LbIDDDM0vgUxC8sgGADUvDChNBDO7cuGyQDzQQphDPopeCqdA4vpShOxRq0p8ou8a0QLEbvZU8fZK0r_Nlr_pbpu9_SSf0Wk2zABU4Zo3e35yTo0EsV79qtUAD9TfJCuKMM_ULRePpmoPSydoKfFzGSHS9zk3OCAMkTTtJQLWNCx33jh6VoaiWVhh3tjjMWcz50QVsZD3S9pRVlBIOnjSgyfxa6-ROCC8IRWJR8uFTLoSOg2nfsWGKhEhATL7Q3SBaWgiDnUuau-8xpNEt_OnFT28h-8nWO6EdJPeP9ipBXs99xDFkQM70AO4jGTz8CGAxRs3cyW5UeVY88lLmzh9Kv0rbLLkFgcTjR_vCfV9WMti9s8xdoP2N-1PcGXb2G9zCEgRiPxEn9Ni0cxNTCUSM1hdFzIPtMb2GvYa0LGSfG5I2oUyWq5Dbmgwd22dYHMNftFuuRtVfRRBJgDaLufgHckGw",
"signature":"wmjZKeH4mZLi2HVp+FLfPBJfS4IajScGySAyXn5yEMs=",
"access_token":"00D90000000vD7X!AQcAQHikT0LLDqcG89y33l4l8c3hbRhGlL22OxLa1iwkQjLPFFw2c.eMYhISttcx7kjcLO_WcuMnDx4EmQ2qd_M76bX5np5a"
}
```

Comment: Add your image, someone will edit the question.

Comment: Can you give fiddle url?

Comment: What does the JavaScript error console say?

Comment: What does the response look like?

Comment: Please update ur fiddle URL

Comment: The url isn't static. It changes because I am using OAuth to access salesforce and the code changes with every request. A sample URL is: "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?code=aPrxaSyVmC8fBbcQDkZFOE6XoAAogOZr7JeAy_IVBWk_qxy1dukTFLuGLlkHCws.bkgxFOJHxQ%3D%3D&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=3MVG9Y6d_Btp4xp6tk21SIcWXJSVDXWORXYkz0_WcT_Xnjl9_A1W5DtxgeROCMzgyqUdl0TUUoOBYGw3Ulucb&client_secret=2348587645368181754&redirect_uri=https://localhost:49711/App/Home/Home.html?isAuthenticated=true"

Comment: You can view a screenshot here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzB2dDYIj0esS0syZzFiREJsT0U/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

If the API you're accessing is under another domain, it may well be that the browser says 'No' because the remote server does not allow [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Basically, this is a security mechanism that prevents requests to other domains, unless the other party specifically allows you to do this with a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, which I don't see in the response headers from SalesForce...

A solution would be to route the request through your own controller first, avoiding this problem.

Comment: This seems to have solved the problem. Instead of sending the request through a web browser, I created a web API Controller and i received the response. I don't have enough reputation points to upvote your answer or I would. Thank you so much

Comment: Incidentally, debugging this is easy. Hit F12 in your browser, and view the console output. You'll see a message explaining the source of the problem.

Comment: I wasn't running it in a traditional browser. This was a task pane app for Office 365.